# Создание динамического теста на 400 вопросов

Tags: php, sql, form

Всем привет. Есть такая проблема. Пишу онлайн тесты для психологического эксперимента.Есть четыре теста и 400 вопросов (по 100 на каждый). У каждого вопроса есть 5 радио кнопок (для оценки от 1 до 5). У каждой группы радио кнопок (для каждого вопроса) должен быть свой уникальный атрибут name. Такой атрибут я получил, но вот как потом в обработчике динамически получять их через post или get (неважно) не знаю.

Вопрос. Как динамически получать ответы на тесты в обработчике. (Как использовать уникальный name).

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста Ваш вопрос. Вы просто хотите через `post` в `php` получить выбранное значение?

Comment: да. Но у каждого блка ответов свое уникальное значение name.

Comment: https://codepen.io/albert-zurabyan/pen/zYGdOBO

Comment: Тут в блоке HTML структура первого теста посмотрите на варианты ответов input type= радио и все будет ясно.

Comment: `name="question[1]"` и на пхп через цикл получаете каждый. Либо `name="question['name']"` .